# Assign value in while condition

Tags: c, sockets, while-loop, variable-assignment

I am new to the c programing and currently I am working on the socket programming, I am confused about what happened below. I have a while loop try to print the value received from the server:

```
while(  recv( sock , buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n",buffer );
};
```

it looks like it doesn't receive anything however if I use the format below:

```
int result;
while( (result = recv( sock , buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n",buffer );
};
```

It works properly, what is the difference between the first one and the second? It looks like recv already returned the value why can't use it directly?

Thanks

Comment: The only difference is that you can use the `result` after the while loop.

Comment: There's not enough information here to know what's happening.  Also, how can you be sure there's a null terminator in your buffer before you print?  `recv()` doesn't add one...

Comment: That is possible.. my quesiton actually is for a general while loop, there should be no difference between the value assignment to result and without it, is this correct in C?

Comment: Yes, the `recv()` call would happen in either case.  And it won't be optimised out, both because its return value isn't known and because it can have effects beyond returning a value for the expression.

Comment: The difference is that the return value from `recv` is available in the loop, so that you *can* terminate the string. That's a huge difference between the two loops. The first loop should never be used, even if the sender is supposed to terminate the string. Relying on the sender means a bug in the sender potentially manifests as a seg fault in the receiver.

Comment: @user3386109 It's not even a question of relying on the sender. With a streaming protocol (e.g. TCP), the terminating NUL might only be received by a latter call to `recv`

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s\n", buffer);` is NOT SAFE. `buffer` is not guaranteed to be NUL-terminated as `%s` requires. You require `result` in order to do this safely.

```
while (1) {
    ssize_t bytes_received = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0);
    if (bytes_received == -1) {
       perror("recv");
       exit(1);
    }

    if (bytes_received == 0) {
       break;
    }

    buffer[bytes_received] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Otherwise, there is no difference between the two.